# How to add TS typing to Vue prop

Tags: typescript, laravel, vuejs2, vite, typing

I have a Vue component that receives a prop `tabs`. This prop is supposed to follow this pattern:

```
[{
  id: string
  title: string
  color: `#${string}`
},{
  id: string
  title: string
  color: `#${string}`
}]
```

I am using Laravel + Vite + Vue 2, and because Vite allows me to use Typescript, I'd like to have my `tabs` prop typed. I know this is possible with JS types, but here I want my custom type above as the type for this prop. I have searched a bit already and didn't find how to do this unless I start using Vue 3 (which won't happen in the current state of my project). So, does anyone know if this is possible, and, if it is, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Install PropType Library: Install the @vue/runtime-core package, which provides utilities like PropType for type-checking in Vue 2.

```
npm install @vue/runtime-core
```

In your Vue component file, you can define the type of the tabs prop using JSDoc annotations along with the PropType utility.

```
// YourComponent.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps } from 'vue';

interface Tab {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  color: string;
}

const props = defineProps<{
  tabs: Tab[];
}>();
</script>
```

use the props object to access the tabs prop with the defined type

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.id">
      <!-- Your tab content here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const { tabs } = props;
</script>
```